# How to install the pygame Python module easily on a mac

Tags: python, pygame

Please help me! I have been looking for a while and I am really frustrated. I can't find a tutorial that I can understand that will help me install pygame. Please post a really easy to understand tutorial as I am fairly new to Python. I am running Mac OSX 10.6 if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml (Scroll down to "Macintosh.")?

Answer (score 1):

I installed pygame recently on 10.6 using the installer linked from the [pygame download page](http://pygame.org/download.shtml):

- http://f0o.com/~rene/stuff/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.6-macosx10.6.mpkg.zip

Comment: When I try to go to that link I get this error:Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~rene/stuff/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.6-macosx10.6.mpkg.zip on this server.

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 with Suhosin-Patch Server at f0o.com Port 80

Comment: I don't know if this is illegal or if there are other issues, but it seems that you could just upload the file that you downloaded to mediafire or some other file sharing site, and then post the link.

Comment: I'll try to remember to do that when I get home later if I still have the file around.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything special to do with the file if you can find it or do I just install the file and it should work?

Comment: I don't recall anything special other than the usual install procedure. Here's the file: http://hewgill.com/~greg/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.6-macosx10.6.mpkg.zip